# TypeScript files compiling on save but not on build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, typescript

#### Problem

I've found that my TypeScript files only compile when I save them. However, when I build or rebuild the project, they do not compile. I'm using TypeScript 0.9.1.1.

When I check the build output of a *new* TypeScript project, it includes the following entry:

```
CompileTypeScript:
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\tsc.exe  --module AMD --sourcemap --target ES3 "app.ts"
```

But my project doesn't produce this in its build output.

#### Setup

Here are the relevant parts of the project file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="Scripts\app\example.ts" />
</ItemGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptIncludeComments>true</TypeScriptIncludeComments>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>true</TypeScriptSourceMap>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptIncludeComments>false</TypeScriptIncludeComments>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>false</TypeScriptSourceMap>
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

#### What I've checked

- The files compile on build in *new* TypeScript projects, so it should be possible.
- The targets file exists in the correct location
- The project file configuration shown above *appears* to be correct when compared with a new TypeScript project
- Compiling a new TypeScript project, which works fine
- [Cannot compile TypeScript files in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13051515/238753), but the symptoms of the problem are different to mine, and it's not clear if the author was using the same setup
- [Typescript will not properly compile in VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16260573/238753), but the symptoms of the problem are different to mine
- The build action for each TypeScript file is set to `TypeScriptCompile` as shown above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After comparing the project file with a new TypeScript project file, I narrowed the problem down to the following:

**The TypeScript targets file must be imported after the C# targets file.**

In the code in the question, fix the problem by moving the following line up:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```