# Preview pane for TypeScript missing and/or not updating in VS2012/13

Tags: typescript, preview, pane

Has anyone got the JavaScript preview pane visible and working in VS2013? I was using it to learn TypeScript in VS2012 but in VS2013 it's gone. I've installed release 2 RC and the latest typescript, but no luck.
On a VS2012 machine the JS pane is not updating, whatever I do. All this from just updating TypeScript?

Comment: I found some strange behavior with the preview pane when using the TypeScriptOutDir option on a project. A quick fix would be to 1. Don't use a TypeScriptOutDir, or 2. Find a ts file that preview is working on and move all other ts files to the same directory as this file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely not using the right build of WebEssentials and Visual Studio combination. Confirm that you're using the build for [VS 2013 RC2](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/56633663-6799-41d7-9df7-0f2a504ca361). The preview pane isn't controlled by anything in nuget. Also make sure that you've removed all old versions of Typescript plugins (from the control panel in Windows) as they aren't needed as of RC2.

As listed in the docs: http://vswebessentials.com/features/typescript

The preview pane has been restored.  I use it, on multiple computers successfully.

Comment: Ok I'm seeing two things to download here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/#Download (1) Download for VS2012, and (2) Get VS 2013 Update 2 RC. I don't see a download for VS2013.

Comment: If you want complete integration with Web Essentials and VS 2013 with the current version of TypeScript, the only option I can confirm works is to use Update 2 RC2 of VS 2013 (and the current builds of Web Essentials).

Comment: The latest version works - I have the preview pane. http://vswebessentials.com/download, select Web Essentials for VS2013. Either it wasn't there yesterday or I am visually challenged.

Comment: See my additional post below regarding the refresh of the preview pane.

Answer (score 0):

Beware of errors due to langue update: Preview pane was restored easily enough using the above instructions. But the huge time waster today was that the preview pane was not updating on save, on rebuild all or with any other attempt to refresh. Even the .JS code was not updating. The problem was there were new errors in the TS, because of the small changes in language support. They did not stop the build from going through successfully - no error messages popping up, successful build, etc. But when I manually viewed the error list, there they were - three errors that occurred in the TypeScript itself. As soon as I fixed these, the preview pane updated automatically again, and the JS refreshed automatically.

Until this latest edition, an error in TS would remove ALL the JS code in the preview pane, and a clear error messages was shown right there. In this latest edition, it's different: The preview does not do anything, no change at all, until the TS errors are fixed.

Comment: Also I had to do this: https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Compile-on-Save Tools->Options->Text Editor->TypeScript->Project. Specifically, enable "Automatically compile TypeScript files which are part of a project".

Comment: That looks like a typo in VS, it says "Automatically compile TypeScript files which are NOT part of a project". Remove the NOT and it makes more sense, since it makes VS compile the TS files that ARE part of the project (they were added to the project by right-clicking and pressing Add, etc.)